# Windows 10: Secondary HDD wakes up when primary SSD is accessed

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sleep

I've got an external 2,5" HDD hooked to my Windows 10 machine with a build in SSD.

Since the HDD only holds media, I'd like the drive to be in standby-mode when ever possible to reduce noise and power consumption.

However, I've noticed that whenever the OS accesses the SSD it also automatically wakes up the HDD. This is also the case when any program tries to access the SSD.

It there a way to prevent this "wake all drives" event and keep the second drive in standby mode?

Comment: Please clarify: How is the external HDD connected (USB ?), which filesystem does it use (NTFS ?).

Comment: Where are allocated the USERS directories, and also the TEMP ones? Where is the pagination file?

Comment: The external hard drive is connected via USB3 and currently uses NTFS. All the user and temp directories a located in the internal SSD where Windows 10 is installed.